# How do I connect my copy GTA Chinatown Wars with Rockstar Social Club?

Tags: rockstar-games-social-club, nintendo-dsi, grand-theft-auto-chinatown-wars

I've tried and tried, and now I just get the following screen:

[image]

(Note the lack of a "Friend Code", even though it was entered.)

The game itself says my stats have been synced fine.

It's been months now :(